# mod_rewrite - переадресация

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Есть допустим адрес http://example.net/image.gif
Далее пишем RewriteCond $1 - КАК выглядит строка $1 (так "/image.gif"  или "image.gif")???
ДАЛЕЕ
Хочу сделать переадресацию с http://example.net/image.gif на http://example.net/folder/image.gif, но только в том случае, если это файл картинки запрашивается(.gif ...).
Вот так пишу, но чет не срабатывает

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(\w*\.gif|\w*\.jpg|\w*\.jpeg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w*\.gif|\w*\.jpg|\w*\.jpeg)$ /folder/$1
```